# Can't run playn-showcase-java (playn sample)

Tags: playn

I an doing: http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted

When I try to do this: 
Click on playn-showcase-java in the Package Explorer
Press Command-Shift-F11 or right click and select Run as → Maven test

I am getting this:

Results :

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (default) @ playn-showcase-java ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
     [java]     at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
     [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.EXTFramebufferObject.glBindFramebufferEXT(EXTFramebufferObject.java:199)
     [java]     at playn.java.JavaGLContext.bindFramebufferImpl(JavaGLContext.java:150)
     [java]     at playn.core.gl.GLContext.viewWasResized(GLContext.java:250)
     [java]     at playn.java.JavaGLContext.initGL(JavaGLContext.java:174)
     [java]     at playn.java.JavaGraphics.init(JavaGraphics.java:155)
     [java]     at playn.java.JavaPlatform.run(JavaPlatform.java:218)
     [java]     at playn.core.PlayN.run(PlayN.java:37)
     [java]     at playn.showcase.java.ShowcaseJava.main(ShowcaseJava.java:28)
     [java] Java Result: 1
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] PlayN Showcase Metaproject ........................ SUCCESS [2.359s]
[INFO] PlayN Showcase Core ............................... SUCCESS [5.828s]
[INFO] PlayN Showcase Java ............................... SUCCESS [22.047s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.125s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 31 12:03:05 EEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I didn't change anything in the code. There are default code of this demo.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphic card must support OpenGL 2.0 for playn.